# join table in sqlalchemy with filtering by groups

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy

table A must be outer-joinned with B.

### A

```
id | ...
---|-----
1  |
2  |   
3  |
---|-----
```

### B

```
id| a_id | b       | ...
--|------|----------
1 |1     | special |
2 |1     | normal  |
3 |2     | normal  |
4 |2     | normal  |
--------------------
```

so I want:

### A.outerjoin(B)

like this:

```
a_id | b.id | ...
-----|------|--------
2    | 3    |normal  |
2    | 4    |normal  |
3    | None |
-----|------|
```

1. what should i use to **filter entire group of B with the same a_id** having at least one "special" value?
2. I dont want lose outerjoin - None for a.id = 3.

my first idea is to use nested select, but it's not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.* 
from a join b on a.id=b.a_id 
where b.b='special';
```

excludes a groups with 'special'

```
select a.* 
from a outer join
    (select distinct a.* 
     from a join b on a.id=b.a_id 
     where b.b='special') excluded on a.id=excluded.id
having excluded.id is null;
```

leaves only valid a rows.

```
select *
from (select a.* 
from a outer join
    (select distinct a.* 
     from a join b on a.id=b.a_id 
     where b.b='special') excluded on a.id=excluded.id
having excluded.id is null) outer join b on a.id=b.a_id;
```

valid rows outer joined with b